# Square Matrix Permutation

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

I have a set of items of size N. The items are sorted by probability. A square matrix m[N][N] of those items, in C style memory organization, would have elements with similar probabilities spread out. For example m[0][100] will be very far from m[100][0] and all others with similar probability. I need to permutate the elements in a simple way so the more likely ones tend to be closer to 0. It doesn't need to be a square matrix, it can be a vector [N*N]. And it doesn't need to be perfect, just good enough that elements with similar probability are somewhat grouped together.

I'm looking for a function f(i,j) to give the position on the permutated matrix/vector. If possible with very simple operations (e.g. no squares and division but programatic conditionals are OK)

For a more graphical reference, I'm looking for something like this. [From BBC's The Story of Maths on Cantor's argument]
[image]

But it doesn't need to be exactly that permutation. Just that the elements walked on the diagonals are mostly grouped nearby.

Well, I know this is probably something very simple but it's been many years since school/uni and Wolframalpha isn't helping.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for space filling curves? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve

Comment: Not necessarily. If there's a convenient one, like the image, with a practical conversion from (i,j) and back, great. But it can be some other way as long as elements of the same diagonal are mostly grouped.

Comment: So in your example `m[0][100]` and `m[100][0]` have the same key (probability here -- I think that calling it probability here is confusing the situation).  So if you call your indexes _i_ and _j_ then the key you want to sort by is `i+j`.  Is this correct?

Comment: @nategoose to be clear, all the elements in the counter-diagonals should be grouped somewhat together. You are right mentioning probability might confuse the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but by the graphic you want a function that describes the mapping of that path, for example f(1,2) = 8.

i+j gives the index of the diagonal, call it d. There are (d+1)d/2 elements in the diagonals above that one. If d is even, we are counting up and to the right, if it is odd we are counting down and to the left, so the number of elements we have counted in the diagonal is j+1 or i+1, respectively:

```
unsigned int f(unsigned int i, unsigned int j)
{
  unsigned int d = i+j;
  unsigned int k = (d+1)*d/2 + (d%2 ? i : j) + 1;
  return(k);
}
```

**EDIT:

I feel like a fool.** The function above works for d<=N, but not d>N (the lower right half of the matrix).

First things first. For some reason I started the index at 1 instead of 0, so that f(0,0) = 1, which isn't really consistent. So if you don't mind I'll remove that `+1`, so that `f(0,0)=0`. Now to deal with the lower right half,

```
unsigned int f(unsigned int i, unsigned int j, unsigned int N)
{
  unsigned int d = i+j;
  if(d>=N)
    return(N*N - f(N-1-i, N-1-j, N) - 1);
  unsigned int k = (d+1)*d/2 + (d%2 ? i : j);
  return(k);
}
```

Comment: +1. however, there's actually no need for the `d%2` part (because the direction on the diagonal doesn't actually matter from the problem statement). and i didn't really see any way of implementing the inverse transform without the use of square roots.

Comment: @lijie: I would expect you to have continuity problems without the `d%2`, but if you don't need it you don't need it. As for the inverse, you can do it without sqrt if you want; it's a tradeoff between simplicity, clarity and efficiency.

Comment: yeah i mean, OP doesn't seem to need it. ok i should clarify. an O(1) inverse without the sqrt [?]

Comment: Very cool and with very fast operations. The thing I'm missing now is how to deal when the diagonal index > N, then the (d+1)*(d/2) prior elements isn't true anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm advancing very slowly, ouch. The vector, as you said, is (i+j). The element position in the vector is min(i, N-j). And the length of the vector N-abs(N-(i+j)). There's got to be something equivalent to (d+1)*d/2 for this... Working on it.

Comment: @lijie: I don't think that's possible, not without something just as bad as sqrt.

Comment: I stupidly disregarded something along the lines, but now that I think of it it's good because the lower-right triangle elements have very low probability so the conditional will barely have mispredictions. On the other hand, N squared isn't a problem since it's a constant and it can be calculated once, and d squared can be calculated in advance and leave it to latency... So my bad on both accounts on a stupidly formulated problem and still you gave a correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Beta so how would you do the inverse without sqrt? a lookupg table of d distances?